# Simple siri integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, siri, sirikit

I'm integrating sirikit to my application.ie, searching flights which might come under ride booking category I guess.

My requirement is simple. If the user asks the Siri, "Hey Siri, search flights for delhi using my app". it will open my app's particular screen where I have the search screen(view controller).

For achieving that, I went through the [sirikit implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH11-SW1) apple document.

What I have tried:

I configured my project with siri capability.
Added an intent extension(obj c language).
Requested siri authorization in appdelegate.
Added String to IntentsSupported in intent info plist.

From here, I need some clarifications and help. I was asked to Set the value of each item to the class name of the intent in the document. While adding intent extension, an intenthandler class file was added. what value should I add to items in info plist there?

Comment: Searching for flights isn't one of the [supported SiriKit intent domains](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH11-SW1)

Comment: @Paulw11, won't it come under ride booking? pl clarify...

Comment: I would think that ride booking is for a service like Uber or a taxi service, but maybe Apple will take a broader view.

Comment: @Paulw11, We're having ticket booking feature in our app. this is not for apple release. Right now we're trying for achieving siri implementation in our app.

Comment: @Paulw11, currently I'm stuck in this issue of adding the value to each item to the class name of the intent handler, I don't know what the class name is?

Comment: It is the class name of your intents extension